# How to estimate the memory used by event listeners in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-listener

When there are more than 10 event listeners, NodeJS alerts a warning:

> (node:56301) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventTarget memory leak detected. 11 abort listeners added to [AbortSignal]. Use events.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
> at AbortSignal.[kNewListener] (node:internal/event_target:426:17)

For the application I am working with, it is fine to have more than 10 event listeners at a given point in time, so I will like to increase the threshold at which this event is triggered. But I need a methodical way to determine what to increase it to. Hence I was thinking, is it possible to estimate the memory used per each event listener? If possible, this can help estimate what the new limit should be.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong. Firstly, node can handle hundreds to thousands of event listeners running in parallel. 10 is nothing. But secondly, each AbortController is expected to have only **ONE** event listener - the one that handles the abort signal. If a single AbortController has more than 10 then you are doing something wrong - probably reusing one abort controller for lots of async operations or accidentally adding multiple event handlers in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Node does nor provide such strict control of memory usage, but helps you to prevent overusage of memory. Event listeners do not consume too much memory, but they can cause a memory leak. You can remove listener limit at all, but make sure that memory leak will not occur

```
emitter.setMaxListeners(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try not to use that much eventListeners, since it consumes more memory

So try to avoid it possible. if you still want it here is the solution.

```js
const { setMaxListeners } = require('events');

const abc = new AbortController()

setMaxListeners(20, abc.signal);

// events module is automatically added to global space, 
// so you can also do this `events.setMaxListeners`, no need to import it.

// ...
```